# Combine module and list of torch.nn.Parameters in one optimizer

Tags: python, pytorch

I have the following code:

```
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([self.model.parameters()] + [self.latent_params_class.latent_params], lr=lr)
```

self.model is a BoTorch SingleTaskGP model (https://botorch.org/tutorials/fit_model_with_torch_optimizer) and self.latent_params_class.latent_params is just a list of torch.nn.Parameter. The above line throws the following error:

```
TypeError: optimizer can only optimize Tensors, but one of the params is Module.parameters
```

How do I put `self.model.parameters()` and `self.latent_params_less.latent_params` into the optimizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue doesn't seem to originate from the `nn.Parameter` but from the fact that you are passing a list containing a parameter generator (in 1st position). A solution is to convert the generator to *list*:

```
model = nn.Linear(10,10)
params = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(10))
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(list(net.parameters()) + [params], lr=1)
```

Comment: that seems a little unnecessary there certainly must be a way to put them together and into the optimizer.

Comment: I have edited my answer, the problem comes from the generator, not the parameter.